# Global exception handler is not working in WEB API- only server

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nlog

I am using NLog for exception handling. Global exception is working fine during development and able to debug exception handler. Properly logging error details into Database.

After deployment in IIS(Windows Server 2016), Global exception handler is not working but NLog working fine other part of code.

It is looks Global exception handler is not calling during any un-handled exception occurred in application.

code snapshots:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
   {
       public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
       {

           // Global Exception Handler
           config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new MyAPP.Utility.MyExceptionHandler());

           // Web API routes

           config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
//Used for logging request and response details
           config.MessageHandlers.Add(new TokenValidatorHandler());
           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
       }

   } 

// handler class

public class MyExceptionHandler : System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandler
   {
       private static readonly Logger Nlog = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

       public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
       {
           try
           {
               Nlog.Error("MyExceptionHandler.Handle : Begin");
               
               var exception = context.Exception;
               
               
               var httpException = exception as HttpException;
               if (httpException != null)
               {
                   context.Result = new CustomErrorResult(context.Request,
                       (HttpStatusCode)httpException.GetHttpCode(),
                        httpException.Message);
                   return;
               }

               context.Result = new CustomErrorResult(context.Request,
               HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
               "Error occured while procesing request.");
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Nlog.Error(ex, "MyExceptionHandler.Handle : Error message : " + ex.Message + " Stacktrace : " + ex.StackTrace);
               
           }

       }
   }
```

NLog is not log first line of handler.
It is working fine if I hosted in IIS of my PC.

Comment: Please show your config

Comment: Does it make sense to re-`throw` the exception in the global exception handler? (throw statement in the catch block)

Comment: I tried with out throw statement but no luck.